# Memory allocation strategies CPU vs GPU on deeplearning (cuda, tensorflow, pytorch,…)

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu, cpu

I'm trying to start multiple processes (10 for example) of learning with tensorflow 2. I'm still using Session and so on multiple `tf.compat.v1` in all my codebase.

- When I'm running with CPU, processes take each around 500mo of CPU memory. `htop` output :
  [image: running on cpu memory usage]
- When I'm running with GPU, processes take each much more CPU memory (like 3Go each) and almost the same (more in reality) GPU memory. `nvtop` output (GPU mem left, CPU <sub>(HOST)</sub> mem right) :
  [image: running on gpu memory usage]

I can reduce GPU memory process fingerprint by using environment variable `TF_CUDNN_USE_AUTOTUNE=0` (1.5Go GPU, not more than 3Go CPU). But it's still much more memory consumption than running process on CPU only. I tried a lot of thing like `TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async` with a tf nightly release, but it's still the same. This cause OOM errors if I would like to keep 10 processes on GPU like on CPU.
I found memory fragmentation may be a hint, by profiling a single process. [You can find screenshots here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45946#issuecomment-922480166).

**TL;DR**
When running tf process on CPU only, it uses some memory (comparable to data size). When running the same tf process on GPU only, it uses much more memory (~x16 without any tensorflow optimization).

I would like to know what can cause a huge difference of memory usage like this, and how to prevent it. Even how to fix it.

FYI -> Current setup : tf 2.6, cuda 11.4 (or 11.2 or 11.1 or 11.0), ubuntu 20.04, nvidia driver 370

**EDIT :** I tried to convert my tensorflow / tflearn code to pytorch. I have the same behaviour (low memory on CPU, and everything explode when running on GPU)

**EDIT2 :** Some of memory allocated on GPU should be for CUDA runtime. On pytorch. I have 300mo memory allocated on CPU run. I have 2go of GPU memory and almost 5go of CPU memory used when running on GPU. May the main problem is the CPU/system memory allocated for this process when I'm running on GPU, since [it seems that CUDA runtime can take almost 2go of GPU mem](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12873#issuecomment-482916237) (this is huge...). It looks like related to CUDA initialization.

**EDIT3 :** This is definitely an issue with CUDA. Even if I try to create a 1,1 tensor with pytorch, it takes 2go of GPU and almost 5go of CPU memory. It can be explain because pytorch is loading a huge number of kernels to memory; even if the main program isn't using them.